# Beginning of sound playback is cut off

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, audio

I am trying to play back a WAV from an embedded resource but it is consistently chopping off anywhere from 0.5 to 2.0 seconds off the beginning. That is, if the WAV is a recorded voice saying "Hello everybody. Today's news..." then the playback typically cuts off "Hello every---" from the start.

The playback code is pretty simple:

```
using System.Media;

play(GetResourceStream(audioItem));

...

private static void play(UnmanagedMemoryStream sndData)
{
   SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(sndData);
   sp.LoadCompleted += delegate( object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
      sp.Play();
   };    
   sp.LoadAsync();
}
```

The original code just created the **SoundPlayer** object then called the **Play()** method. I added the **LoadAsync()** call and **LoadCompleted** event handler to see if that fixed the problem but it doesn't seem to behave any differently.

Additional information: It appears that sound playback is only chopped off the very first time the app calls **SoundPlayer.Play()**.  Subsequent calls seem to work OK.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem. The beginning of the sound is cut both in app and when played via an external media player (like VLC). In my case, the issue was related to Bluetooth speakers. After switching the sound output to the wired speakers, it worked fine.

Comment: I had the same issue but I solved it in the opposite way: I switched from wired to bluetooth (this was on a mac).

Comment: This issue is with me on a speaker connected with USB wire. Tried both nulling the registry settings about Idlesomething and turning off the power asving in USV hub settings in Device manager -- nothing helps. The speaker sleeps after ~3.5 seconds and lags the first 0.5sec of any sound after that.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a problem. Try to put the wav to a file and play from file. If the problem still occurs, I think you should check your sound card's settings for various effects, such as fade.

Try to play "C:\Windows\Media\chord.wav", it's very short, even less then a second.

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\chord.wav");
player.Play();
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I don't think this helps. The sound **is** in a file. As an embedded resource, it's stored within the program's EXE file. It's not loaded into RAM until the program needs it. The **LoadASync** call loads the sound into RAM and calls the **LoadCompleted** handler once that's done.  The event handler then calls the **Play** function.

There are no sound card settings involved which could affect playback.

Comment: I understand it's in a file, embedded. Still, they can be handled differently. You should try both experiments and report the observations... If you want to solve the issue, of course.

Comment: Sorry, but I just don't see how such experimenting would help.

Let's say I tried having the sound in its own file and the problem still exists. That doesn't put me any closer to a solution.

Let's say I tried it and the problem did NOT exist. This still doesn't put me any closer to a solution. I do not have the option of having the sound data in separate files. They have to be embedded resources.

Comment: Testing file storage helps to narrow the problem. Testing a short sound shows if it's a problem of skipping the beginning or whatever sound effect issue, for example. If you're unwilling to spend a minute doing simple tests, you're on your own.

Comment: OK, just for the sake of argument, I tried playing a sound from a file using the code you posted. The sound is not played. Now that we've narrowed things down the way you wanted, what's the solution?

Comment: I don't think there's a need for confrontation. The same code sample plays just fine for me, and I believe for anyone else, as a quick google search didn't show anything interesting. The next tests would be: 1) Try to play the "chord" sound with a regular sound player 2) Go to Control panel | Sound and test-play a short sound, ex. "Critical stop" 3) Trigger the sound from system (which is closest to your case) - ex. try to rename a file and put a \ in its name, a sound will play. 4) Set your own sound as system sound an test it as in (2) and (3)

Comment: I'm not worried about confrontation one way or the other. I just don't want to waste time doing tests that don't have any possibility of revealing information that can help me fix the problem.

Playing CHORD.WAV with "regular sound player" works fine.  Playing short sounds in control panel works fine.  #3 and #4 work fine.

If I had a problem with my computer's sound output in general, I would have been working to solve that before I worried about anything else.

Comment: If it helps you, in my team I'm known for being able to solve the most tangled mysteries. It isn't like you're going to spend hours doing what I requested. And it's your call whether you want to solve the problem or not. Maybe you wanted someone to miraculously tell you "open file xxx, go to line yyy, put zzz and your problem is solved"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36084/discussion-between-codeguard-and-mike-fulton)

Answer (score 0):

If you have no problem with "synchronous" playing, just try [`SoundPlayer.PlaySync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playsync(v=vs.110).aspx) method. That worked well for me in the exact same case (i.e. with "embedded resource"s).

Comment: Has to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was indeed the bluetooth speakers...i disconnected then reconnected and it worked fine after that.  I didn't have to switch to wired speakers.

the problem was happening on two different microsoft players AND VLC.